# Installing Gulp locally fails

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp

I have Node.js and npm installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
nodejs -v
v0.10.25

node -v
v0.10.25

npm -v
1.3.10
```

I have also installed Gulp globally with `npm install gulp -g`.

```
gulp -v
CLI version 3.9.0
```

Now in my project when I try to install Gulp locally with `npm install gulp` I get a lot of errors. I have copied them to Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/VWdPLNQS

If I try to run `gulp watch` in my project directory, I get

```
Local gulp not found in /var/www
Try running: npm install gulp
```

What do I need to do?

I tried this on Windows too. The Ubuntu installation is running with Vagrant. I have it installed so that it shares the /var/www directory with the host machine.

First I downloaded Node.js from their website and after that I ran

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
```

No errors. Then I opened command prompt in Windows and changed directory to the folder where /var/www is linked. I ran `npm install`. My package.json contains the following

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

No errors. I tried running gulp in the Ubuntu terminal after this installation but I got errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'isobject'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch/node_modules/braces/node_modules/expand-range/node_modules/fill-range/index.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I switched to Windows and run gulp, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install never version of Node.js and NPM:

- Remove `node_modules`, then remove gulp globally and locally.
- After that make sure you are on newer nodejs, like 6+
- Install gulp globally
- Check permissions on folder you are trying to use, run `chown [your_user_name] [folder_name] -R`

I think updating node/npm update should resolve your problem.